# Calculated measures in MSSQL Server 2008 BDS cube

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx, data-warehouse, olap, cube

I want to define 3 calculated members. I have a cube based on 2 tables, TrackInfo and Chart Positions. Chart Positions table consists of 36 week columns, which contain given track's position on top 100 list in given week (or 0 if the song didn't make it on the list):

```
[Entry ID] FOREIGN KEY,
[1st Week] FLOAT,
[2nd Week] FLOAT,
```

and so on, until week 36.

I'd like to calculate the following measures:

1) The amount of weeks the song has been in top 10

2) The amount of weeks the song has been in top 20

3) "Popularity meter", which would be done by the formula:

1 / ((average of all nonzero positions) * (37 - (weeks featured on List)))

Can anyone help me with those?

Comment: Cube made with Business Development Studio 2008, sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I see. When you say you have a cube based on 2 tables, do you mean 2 dimension tables? Do you also have a fact table?

Comment: I have 3 dimensions: Chart positions, artist data and miscellaneous data. I have 1 measure which is total tracks count. Chart positions dimension contains all 36 week columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit difficult without the cube definition to write some MDX but for 1) I'll take as example a similar question - number of year [Tokyo] has been in the Top 3 selling city :

```
 select
  [Measures].[Sales] on 0,

  Filter( 

    Generate( [Time].[Year].[Year].members as s1, 
             TopCount( s1.currentMember * [Customers].[City].members, 3, [Measures].[Sales] ) 
    ) as s2,

    IIF( s2.current(1) IS [Customers].[Geography].[City].[Tokyo] , true, false )

  )

  on 1 

  from [Sales]
```

This works with a demo cube available in [icCube](http://www.icCube.com); should be the same with AS as this is quite standard MDX. I think you'll get the idea with the [Generate](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Generate.html) function. Then you can create a calculated measure that will Count() the filtered set instead of putting this set on the axis (for the demo purpose).